# How to get to Workbook from Window

Tags: excel, vsto, vba

I have a [Window object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/window-object-excel) and need to get corresponding [Workbook](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/workbook-object-excel) because I need to know .FullName but I can't figure out how to get there. Seems like impossoible from the MSDN documentation ?

Comment: It's almost impossible to know your situation and how to assist you, with the none-information you provided. Try giving us more information to work with, such as how many workbook do you have open ? Do you have a few Excel instances open, or just one ? Share your latest code attempt could help as well

Comment: Sorry but how can you say no information. You first better to learn to behave and only then use sites like StackOverflow.

Comment: I wasn't trying to insult you, but if you want people to help you need to provide more information, and also share your code attempt. Besides, I have been a member here a little longer than you, contributing "just a little more".

Comment: I don't know much about Excel API model but I know that what I asked for is simple that it doesn't require repro code. Why number of workbooks matter ? It's irrelevant because I said I have a WInodw object. Why number of Excel instances matter ? There can be any - I don't write this for a lab but real environment. Code attempt - it'd reduce question to very specific because I invoke this from .NET to find path of opened Excel file ... .

Comment: And Domenic answered it very well. And he also is here shorter so don't think that if you have a bit better reputation than a complete newbie you're always right. Try to really help and if you can't, you don't need to immediately punish people by downvoting because you don't get the point

Comment: I didn't down vote your post, too bad you're assuming the worst in everyone, I just suggested from my experience that most helping users here won't answer such a post. Also, not sure you got the best most reliable answer, but since you are not willing to share the situation information, you will use that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the Parent property to return the Workbook object...

```
ActiveWindow.Parent
```

And then you can use the FullName property to return the path and filename...

```
ActiveWindow.Parent.FullName
```

Comment: Let me guess your on a Mac too! (Office 365?) Gone are the days where you can access object model and it's properties from drop down lists